# Convert part of a text string to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

how could I use javascript/jquery to replace the entire string below with `<img src="img.domain.com/deal/7chstJKMJrTjcBWCTf4H/He-450x300">`

Also bearing in mind that everything after /deal/ could change

String:

```
{"path":"img.domain.com/deal/7chstJKMJrTjcBWCTf4H/He-450x300","deal_uuid":"f8da6d47-a1f2-4e59-898d-b52d2b28636e","ordering":0}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where is this source text?  Why do you need to replace the text?  How?  It looks like the source String is JSON, so how is that being incorporated.

Comment: You probably need that src to start with http, unless you have a local folder called img.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your string is in a javascript variable of "JSONString"

```
var jqObj = $.parseJSON(JSONString);
var el = $("<img/>");
el.attr('src', jqObj.path);
```